# Project contains C++ files but it is not using a supported native build system error after converting Eclipse project to android Studio

Tags: android, android-ndk

After migrating an Eclipse project to android studio I am getting below error. Actually one of the third party library is using jni and I have installed CMake, LLDB and NDK. But the error still exists. Please help me.

> "Your project contains C++ files but it is not using a supported
>   native build system. Consider using CMake or ndk-build integration
>   with the stable Android Gradle plugin:"

Answer (score 6):

The fastest way to get building is this:

(1) Locate the Android.mk file that was used to build your native code before. This is usually somewhere under the project root. Make note of the path, you'll need it in a minute. Let's call it ~/projects/myproject/myapp/src/main/jni/Android.mk.

(2) Find the build.gradle for that application. It should be in an ancestor folder of Android.mk. In our example, it would be located at ~/projects/myproject/myapp/build.gradle. If that file doesn't have "apply plugin: 'com.android.application'" near the top then it is probably the wrong one.

(3) Edit that build.gradle to point to the Android.mk file. So, add a section like this:

```
android {
    externalNativeBuild {
        ndkBuild {
            path "src/main/jni/Android.mk"
        }
    }
}
```

(4) Click "Sync Now" in Android Studio (or Build/Refresh Linked C++ Projects)

At this point, there's a good chance the build will just work. If not, we have a new issue to deal with.

FWIW, you can automate step 3 by following the steps here: https://developer.android.com/studio/projects/add-native-code.html#link-gradle